# Disabling Multitouch in Ubuntu

Tags: touchpad, touchegg

Since Ubuntu has decided to arbitrarily remove certain gestures for laptop users (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1172172), I'm trying to to replace the built in gestures with touchegg. I'm following the instructions from this site to remove the built in gestures:
https://ineed.coffee/1625/how-to-disable-unity-default-multi-touch-gestures-in-ubuntu/

They seem to be working for everyone else but due to some reason when I try to 'build' unity it goes to about 90% and then gives me this error:

fatal error: libindicator/indicator-desktop-shortcuts.h: No such file or directory

I get this on the file Unity-*->launcher->ApplicationLauncherIcon.h line 29.

Am I missing something?

And thanks, first post here.